# Adding button click event crashes app at launch

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have the following Java code for my button event. This code doesn't generate any error at compile-time, but the app crashes during launch.

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
    b0.setOnClickListener(this);

}

String t = "";
TextView inp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input);

public void onClick(View v)
{
    if (v == findViewById(R.id.button0))
    {
        t = "0";
        inp.setText(inp.getText()+t);
    }
}
```

The Xml Code is :

```xml
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/dbtn"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dbtn"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"

    android:text="0" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TextView inp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input);
```

Put the above line inside `onCreate()` method after you call `setContentView()` and change you TextView variable scope from local to global.

This should fix the issue. If you still having trouble, let me know.

Comment: Not working. As soon as I paste the line below setContentView(), my onClick method generates an obvious error for inp going out of scope

Comment: Hey, I just tried pasting that line in my onClick() method, and it Worked!!!Thanks al lot !:)

Comment: Yes, I hope you got the point that you can't call findViewById() before calling setContentView(). Please accept the answer, if it helped you solve the issue. Thanks